# transform list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this result

{'BetweenessCentrality': {('A', 'B'): }

I want to transform this to pandas dataframe

| User X | User Y | Betweeness_Centrality |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 5.8772289370698734e-05. |

I have done
 `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':results[f]})`

|                           Betweeness_Centrality                                           |

| Betweeness_Centrality |{('00cancelled', 'zerohedge'): 5.877228937069                      |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
results = {'BetweenessCentrality': {('A', 'B'): 5.87e-05}}

out = pd.DataFrame(results).rename_axis(['User X', 'User Y']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  User X User Y  BetweenessCentrality
0      A      B              0.000059
```